# Issue with a where clause by using Oracle

Tags: oracle, trigger, plsql

I'm currently facing a problem while I'm adding a trigger to the database that I use at home.

I'm using : Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.1.0 - 64bit Production

The problem that occurs is that, when I add my trigger it compiles, but impossible to access to the content of a VARCHAR2 variable, even if it contains something.

```
    typeEngine engine.type%TYPE = '74E';--engine.type is a VARCHAR2(4)

SELECT engine.capacity INTO capacityMax
FROM engine
WHERE engine.type = typeEngine;
```

That returns me a NO DATA FOUND Exception, but the data is in the database.

Thanking you all in advance if someone has the solution to solve that issue.

Comment: similar problem was here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8401785/oracle-no-data-found-but-data-exists

Comment: @Franek OP explicitly stated `engine.type` is `varchar2(4)` so this can't be `char` vs. `varchar2` issue.

Comment: I assume that you have an id field. Please show us the output of the following [query](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/server.121/e17209/functions061.htm#SQLRF51375): 

`SELECT DUMP(engine.type, 1016),engine.type
  FROM engine
where engine.id=12345;`

The expression ´where id=12345´ should be replaced by an appropriate expression.
Maybe  `type` is an [sql or pl/sql keyword](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/server.121/e17209/ap_keywd.htm#SQLRF022) so replace `engine.type` by `engine."TYPE"` in your pl/sql code to avoid ambiguities and run your code again.

Comment: Can you show the entire trigger script? Including the create or replace

Answer (score 1):

It may probably no longer be a problem, but in the code it seems you forgot that the assignment operator is :=, not =, so typeEngine would be null and the query returns no rows.